# How do I set up crossplay in Destiny 2?

Tags: destiny-2

I’m trying to play *Destiny 2* with my brother but he has a different console. I play on Xbox and he plays on PS4. I can't seem to add him as a friend. What should I do?

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, at the time of writing, what you are trying to do is not possible. While Destiny 2 does support cross-save, cross-play play is not supported. So for the time being, the best you can be apart of the same clan, but in order to add each other as friends and play together , you will need to be playing on the same console.

[Bungie](https://www.bungie.net/en/News/Article/50124) has confirmed that cross-play will be implemented in the future. The news article states cross-play will be available in Season 15 (Destiny 2 is currently is Season 13). However, due note this may be subject to change at Bungie's discretion.

Comment: Just adding a note to say that cross-play is now live, as of 24th August 2021. You can now add "Bungie friends" which covers cross-platform friends.